# Is there a way to assign network and binding ports to a docker agent in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, agent

I have the next setup:

- one amazon EC2 instance;
- Jenkins installed on it;
- Docker instance installed along with Jenkins

When I am starting the container (in a pipeline script) I am trying to add also the host network and also binding ports.

```
node {
    docker.image('localhost:5000/build_deploy_agent:base').withRun('-t --network host -p 9101:9101') { c ->
        sh 'doing stuff'
    }
}
```

I need this because at the end I want to keep the container alive with the deployed application.

The problem is, no network or ports are assigned to the container. Only the -t command is taken in consideration.

[image]

Is there a way to do this or I am losing time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if the network is visible through inspection, instead of just `docker ps`.
See "[How to find the network my container is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43904562/6309)"

```
docker inspect <lyContainer> -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
```

Or you could [filter docker ps by network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#network), again, to check if the containers were assigned to the expected network.

You can also [check your network stack](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#procedure) through a Jenkins step like `ip addr show` to see if a new network interface was created.

Comment: Thank you and I sorry for the delay in replying to you. In fact I checked the network of my opened containers right before I saw your answer, and I realized that this is a very stupid question (you cannot have a container running with 'host' network and binding ports setup. Docker throws an error). I have tried it before directly with docker, and started two containers on the 'host' network with biding ports. For some weird reason this worked. When I checked the networks, both containers were started with 'bridge' connection, and this is why the connection with the host was running OK.